# Doctrine 2 join on PK in JSONb field

Tags: doctrine, inner-join, jsonb

In our system we have table to track events. This table named `Event` have a JSONb column `source` to hold references to entities in other tables:

```
| uuid                                 | name                                      | source                                                   |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 7916c5c9-3af2-41ce-81e4-776847029b08 | App\LoginRequest\LoginRequestExpiredEvent | {"loginRequest": "4dda7873-534d-4c0c-853b-65b4b1056dae"} |
```

Simplified `login_request` table looks like this:

```
| uuid                                 | expireAt            |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
| 4dda7873-534d-4c0c-853b-65b4b1056dae | 2019-02-14 08:00:00 |
| 13c85e8c-e2dc-4b3f-aaf5-25920e2c4d04 | 2019-02-14 22:00:00 |
```

I would like to SELECT all LoginRequest entities that **are referenced** in Event table. Please remember that both table doesn't have any foreing-key relation! LoginRequest is referenced only via JSONb field. RAW SQL works like expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM login_request AS lr
JOIN event AS ev ON ev.source->>'loginRequest' = text(lr.uuid)
```

returning resultset like:

```
| lr.uuid                              | lr.expireAt         | ev.uuid                              | ev.name                                   | ev.source                                                |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 4dda7873-534d-4c0c-853b-65b4b1056dae | 2019-02-14 08:00:00 | 7916c5c9-3af2-41ce-81e4-776847029b08 | App\LoginRequest\LoginRequestExpiredEvent | {"loginRequest": "4dda7873-534d-4c0c-853b-65b4b1056dae"} |
```

I have troubles to get the same functionality as RAW SQL in Doctrine's DQL:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

class LoginRequestRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, LoginRequestEntity::class);
    }

    public function findExpiredWithEvent()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('lr');
        $qb
            ->select('lr')
            ->join(
                EventEntity::class,
                'ev',
                Join::ON,
                "ev.source->>'loginRequest' = text(lr.uuid)"
            );

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

I cannot make JOIN on JSONb field prop work. For example above query-builder invocation returns exception:

```
In QueryException.php line 54:

  [Syntax Error] line 0, col 104: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'


In QueryException.php line 43:

  SELECT lr FROM App\LoginRequest\LoginRequestEntity lr
  INNER JOIN App\Event\EventEntity ev
  ON ev.source->>'loginRequest' = text(lr.uuid)
```

Is there posibility to do a JOIN on JSONb column property from other table in Doctrine's query-builder?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar sql :

```
select distinct lru.id, lru.* from tstdf_lru as lru inner join tsrec_failure as failure on failure.lru_id = lru.id inner join wrks_event as event on failure.failure_group_id = (event.data->>'failureGroupId')::BIGINT
```

Maybe that can help you.